# Disable Client Side Validation with ASP.NET 5

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

How to disable Client Side Validation with ASP.NET 5?

I tried to set ClientValidationEnabled to false in config.json like [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5) but I still have `data-val-*` attributes in html elements.

**Answer :**

```
services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureMvcViews(options =>
        {
           options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
        });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe configuring this via AppSettings is supported out of the box in ASP.NET 5. One option is to programmatically configure this in your `Startup` class's `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddViewOptions(options =>
            {
                options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
            });

    }
```

The `ClientValidationEnabled` was moved to an `HtmlHelperOptions` property on `MvcViewOptions`.

Comment: Thanks. For information AddViewOptions has been renamed to ConfigureMvcViews.

Comment: @StevenMuhr why can't I find out `ConfigureMvcViews` method? But the code example (`AddViewOptions`) works in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: @Ricky At the time I was working with beta6. It has been renamed in beta7. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/62 => PART3

Comment: If you are coming from ASP.NET Core 5 you can do this. `services.AddRazorPages().AddViewOptions(options => { ... }) ;` or `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().AddViewOptions(opts => { });`